# remove emails in queue (only from specific sender)

Tags: linux, email, exim, queue

There's almost 50k mails in my queue when i type "exim -bpc". I need to clean the mess ASAP before i get blacklisted by gmail, as these mails are being forwarded to my personnal gmail account.

How can i delete all mails from a specific sender e-mail address (or with a specific subject name) so i can target only the trash and still receive the legitimate mails ?

Thanks!

> exim -bpc 
>   Blockquote

46582

Answer (score 1):

For a given sender:

```
# exim -q | awk '/sender@example.com/ {print $3}' | xargs exim -Mrm
```

The sender is listed as 4th field on the first line for each message; the internal queue ID is shown as 3rd field. So the `awk` command searches for the specified sender address, and for matching lines prints the 3rd field. This is fed into `xargs` which gathers up words on its standard input and runs the specified command with as many of those words as fit on a normal command line. `exim -Mrm` takes a list of queue IDs and removes those messages from the queue (mnemonic: `rm` is the Unix remove command).